# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client/ Server crashes with this when page refreshes

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

Made a Question a few days ago on here, thought I had it figured out, even accepted the answer, because it was right regardless. but now I have the Same issue, same error.

Heres the Error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/apple/Documents/Web Dev/collab/Backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/apple/Documents/Web Dev/collab/Backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/apple/Documents/Web Dev/collab/Backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at /Users/apple/Documents/Web Dev/collab/Backend/routes/index.js:90:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Heres Index.js. Line 90 is at the very bottom,
@ router.get("/", isAuth, (req, res)

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const genPassword = require("../lib/passwordUtils").genPassword;
const connection = require("../config/database");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.models.User;
const isAuth = require("./authMiddleware").isAuth;
// cors is needed with router.use else you have to put routes on the app.js
const cors = require("cors");
router.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3001", credentials: true }));
// const isAdmin = require("./authMiddleware").isAdmin;
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/**
 * -------------- Post ROUTES ----------------
 *
 */

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else if (!user) {
      res.send("No User Exists");
    } else {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(user);
        return;
        // console.log(req.user);
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const saltHash = genPassword(req.body.repeatPassword);

  const salt = saltHash.salt;
  const hash = saltHash.hash;

  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.firstInput,
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    title: "",
    hash: hash,
    salt: salt,
  });

  newUser.save().then((user) => {});
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

/**
 * -------------- GET ROUTES ----------------
 *
 */

router.post("/user", (req, res) => {
  const fName = req.body.firstInput;
  const lName = req.body.secondInput;

  const title = req.body.repeatPassword;

  const user = req.session.passport.user;
  User.updateOne(
    { _id: user },
    { fName: fName, lName: lName, title: title },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(401);
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      }
    }
  );
});
router.get("/", isAuth, (req, res) => {
  const userMap = {};
  User.find({}, function (err, users) {
    users.forEach(function (user) {
      userMap[user._id] = user;
    });
    return userMap;
  })
    .then((response) => {
      res.status(200).json({ user: req.user, auth: true, response });
      return;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Heres App.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const routes = require("./routes");
const isAuth = require("./routes/authMiddleware").isAuth;
const connection = require("./config/database");
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3001", credentials: true }));
const User = mongoose.models.User;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  collection: "sessions",
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "zdfbdaf",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      cookie: { secure: false },
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

require("./config/passport");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/", routes);

app.listen(3000);
```

heres authMiddleware.js

```
module.exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    // res.status(200).json({ user: req.user, auth: true });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ auth: false });
  }
};

// module.exports.isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
//     if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.admin) {
//         next();
//     } else {
//         res.status(401).json({ msg: 'You are not authorized to view this resource because you are not an admin.' });
//     }
// }
```

Heres passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const connection = require("./database");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.models.User;
const validPassword = require("../lib/passwordUtils").validPassword;
const cors = require("cors");
passport.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3001" }));

const customFields = {
  usernameField: "username",
  passwordField: "password",
};

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(customFields, (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username })
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          console.log("No user");
          return done(null, false);
        } else {
          const isValid = validPassword(password, user.hash, user.salt);
          if (isValid) {
            console.log("Logged in");

            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            console.log("Wrong Password");
            return done(null, true);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  })
    .then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch((err) => done(err));
});
```

It only crashes half the time, kind of? It works at first, until you refresh the page. I am at a loss. Had someone in the discord also not know the issue. I'm begging for some help here. I'm losing my mind.

Comment: Are you sure this is the authMiddleware.js file

Comment: oh shoot good catch. my copy and paste messed up i guess. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you are calling done twice once after finding the user
and second after .then block in passport.deserializeUser function

this will work:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user)   
  });
});
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you so much.